# SPOJ - Prime Path (PPATH)

Tags: c++, graph

I am trying to solve SPOJ problem "[Prime Path](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PPATH/)":

> The question is to find the least possible way to convert a 4 digit
>   prime number to another 4 digit prime number by changing one one digit
>   at a time and also the intermediate values are also a prime number.

I am doing a bfs in my solution. In the convert function i am changing the digit in the corresponding positions of the number.

1. ones
2. tens
3. hundreds
4. thousands

My solution code is as below. I am getting wrong answer in the first test case itself . I would be glad if anyone could find the bug in my programe.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
// My Terms
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define ins insert
#define fir first
#define sec second
#define PRINT(x)        cout << #x << " " << x << endl
#define pi acos(-1)
#define ll long long
#define EM empty()
#define sz(a) int((a).size())
#define all(c) (c).begin(),(c).end()
#define fill(a,v)     memset(a, v, sizeof(a))

using namespace std;

unsigned long long mod=1000000007;

bool isprime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(number); i++) {
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

long long convert(long long num,int position ,int value) // position is ones tens hundreds etc
{
    int ones=num%10;num/=10;
    int tens=num%10;num/=10;
    int hunderds=num%10;num/=10;
    int thousands=num%10;num/=10;

    if(position==1)
    {
        return ( (thousands*1000) +(hunderds*100) + (tens*10) + (value)  );
    }
    else if (position==2)
    {
        return ( (thousands*1000) +(hunderds*100) + (value*10) + (ones)  );
    }
    else if (position==3)
    {
        return ( (thousands*1000) +(value*100) + (tens*10) + (ones)  );
    }
    else if (position==4)
    {
        return ( (value*1000) +(hunderds*100) + (tens*10) + (ones)  );
    }
}

int n;long long  l,m;

int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    while(n)
    {
        cin>>l>>m;

        long long level=0;
        queue<  pair< int,int >  > q;
        q.push(make_pair(l,0) );

        int visited[10010]={0};
        visited[l]=1;

        int flag=0;
        while(q.size())
        {
            l=q.front().first;
            level=q.front().second;
            q.pop();

            if(l==m)
            {
                cout<<level<<"\n";
                flag=1;
                break;
            }

            //cout<<l<<" "<<level <<"\n";

            for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
            {
                /////////////////////////////
                // for thousands's place digit
                if(i>0)
                {
                    long long a2=convert(l,4,i);

                    if(   visited[a2]!=1 && isprime(a2) )
                    {
                        q.push( make_pair( a2,level+1 ) );
                        visited[a2]=1;
                    }

                }

                //////////////////////////////////
                // for hunderd's place digit

                long long b2=convert(l,3,i);

                if(  visited[b2]!=1 && isprime(b2) )
                {
                    //cout<<a2<<"\n";
                    q.push( make_pair( b2,level+1 ) );
                    visited[b2]=1;
                }

                ////////////////////////////
                // for ten's place digit
                long long c2=convert(l,2,i);

                if(  visited[c2]!=1 && isprime(c2) )
                {

                    q.push( make_pair( c2,level+1 ) );
                    visited[c2]=1;
                }

                ////////////////////////////
                // for one's place digit
                long long d2=convert(l,1,i);

                if(  visited[d2]!=1 && isprime(d2) )
                {
                    //cout<<a2<<"\n";
                    q.push( make_pair( d2,level+1 ) );
                    visited[d2]=1;
                }
            }

        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            cout<<"Impossible"<<"\n";
        }

        n--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's with all those `#define`s? Are you trying to obfuscate your code?

Comment: sorry for the #defines ..These are added automatically by codeblock as  my pre-statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `isprime` function. It incorrectly returns `true` for the following numbers:

> 0, 1, 4, 9, 25, 49, 121, 169, 289, 361, 529, 841, 961, 1369, 1681, 1849, 2209, 2809, 3481, 3721, 4489, 5041, 5329, 6241, 6889, 7921, 9409

With the exception of `0` and `1`, all of these happen to be squares of prime numbers.

You can solve it by changing

```
for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(number); i++) {
```

into

```
for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(number); i++) {
```

This will make your function return `true` wrongfully only for the digits numbers `0` and `1`, but that does not matter for this particular problem.

However, a much more efficient way is to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Here's a code example for that one.

```
std::vector<bool> sieve(int largest)
{
    std::vector<bool> is_prime(largest+1, true);
    is_prime[0] = is_prime[1] = false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= largest; ++i) {
        if (is_prime[i]) {
            for (int j = 2*i; j <= largest; j += i) {
                is_prime[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return is_prime;
}
```

And then you can simply use `is_prime[number]` for an O(1) lookup.

**Disclaimer**: I did not try to submit your code with the `isprime` function fixed. There may be other issues, but it looks okay to me. Your logic is the same as my accepted solution, and from what I've seen you're not missing any edge cases.

Comment: Thank you @bart . The error was obviously in the isprime() function. i got it accepted. Thank you very much.